# Is it possible to use openocd to program an atmega using an AVR ISP (mk2)?

Tags: avr, atmega, programming, avrdude, openocd

I have an ATMega2560 on a custom board which I want to program with my AVRISP mkii.

I have successfully programmed it using the Arduino IDE, and also over the commandline using avrdude.

Is there a built-in "interface" config/script which is likely to work? I'm not even really sure what setting to use for the "interface" (e.g. `ft2232`, `buspirate`).

Comment: Why do you want to use OpenOCD? Use the tool that works.

Comment: @TurboJ Good point. I guess I'm wanting to minimise the difference between configuratons if possible. I thought OpenOCD was somewhat of an abstraction, potentially allowing different chips to be uploaded/debugged with only a few small changes. Cheers tho!

Comment: Also, if you think the answer is "you can't, out of the box", post that and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe openOCD even supports the Atmel AVRISP mk2. The list of supported dongles is [here](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Debug-Adapter-Hardware.html#Debug-Adapter-Hardware). OpenOCD uses the [JTAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Test_Action_Group) communication protocol to communicate with, set breakpoints, and control its target processors and FPGA's (IEEE standard 1149.1 in case you care). The Atmel AVRISP mk2 does not communicate using this protocol (in general). In limited cases it supports programming using something like it, but it isn't fully 1149.1 compatible -- so it isn't even likely that someone will add support for it to OpenOCD.